# Python Selenium - list index out of range

Tags: python, list, selenium

I'm trying Selenium for the very first time.
I'm facing a strange problem trying to access a list of elements.

I have an HTML table (1 row, 7 cols) and I want to access an exact column of an exact row. This is the WORKING code:

```
table_id = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "table_class")
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:     # not necessary, I only have 1 row
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for col in cols: # not necessary, I only need to access the 5th elem
        print(col.text)
```

The problem is that if I try to use the indexes it doesn't works

```
cols = rows[0].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
for col in cols:
 print(col.text)
```

Or if I try to access only the 5th column using `cols[4]` I always get `list index out of range`.
I can't understand why it works using the for loop but I cannot access using indexes.
Thanks

Comment: `row[0]` should be `rows[0]`

Comment: Yes sorry it is. It still gives me `list index out of range`

Comment: Are you sure the first code is working? do you have any output on the console? you should also post the relevant html.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. However, I just solved thanks to @ignacioct answer. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you only have one row. Maybe because you use a for loop, It gets through a row that is empty of the elements you are looking for, therefore returning an empty list and showing you the error.

Another solution would be, try to access the elements by XPATH.

```py
rows = table_id.find_elements_by_xpath("""""")
```

And do the same for `cols` variable as well.

Comment: How would using `xpath` make any difference?

Comment: It's the safest option when it comes to finding elements without any troubles. Trying to find elements by let's say TAG_NAME could be tricky and may not always work, so xpath is the way to go.

Comment: *It's the safest option* you base that on what? and searching by tag name is based on `xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access the `row` variable, that was defined only for iterating the loop. Shouldn't it be `cols = rows[0].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")`?

Comment: Yes it is sorry. I did a typo reporting it here.